Segmentation fault after sorting my matrix
I implemented this program and I got segmentation fault and I do not know why, can someone explain.
Problem:
Let's call one row of the matrix better than another row if its largest element is larger
from the largest element of that second order. Create a generic function "SortByOrderGoodness"
which as a parameter as the only parameter some matrix (which can be humpbacked) organized
as a vector of vectors of an arbitrary type of elements, which are only assumed to be possible
compare by size The function should transform that matrix so that it becomes sorted by
"goodness" of rows in ascending order, in the sense that after sorting, its first row is the row that
is the "best" in the previously described sense, then the next order of "goodness" follows, and so on
to the last line, which should be the "worst". If two rows have the same "goodness", then
the order that is higher (iyour text that comes later) according to the lexicographic order should come first.
The function does not return any result, but only modifies the matrix that is passed to it as a parameter.
The requested function must be implemented with the help of the "sort" function from the header library
"algorithm", to which the appropriate criteria function should be passed, which should be performed as
named function called "Criterion". In addition, that criteria function must not use any
loops (but may call other functions from the same library).
Demonstrate the written function in a test program in which the elements of the matrix of integers are humped
numbers are entered line by line, with the end-of-line mark being anything other than a number (say “”).
Entry ends when something other than a number is entered immediately at the beginning of the line. After it's done
input, the program should sort the matrix as described, and print its elements after
done sorting. Finally, after printing, the program should ask for the input of some elements
sequence of integers, after which it tests whether the sequence is entered using a binary search procedure
appears as one of the rows of the previously entered matrix. Depending on the test results, the program should
in case of a successful search, print the sentence "The searched sequence is located in . order (after
sorting)", where  is the matrix row that is identical to the entered sequence (after done
sorting), i.e. the sentence "The requested sequence is not found in the matrix" in case of failure
searches. If there are several lines that are identical to the entered sequence, the first of them should be reported. For
search, use only the "lower_bound" function from the library with the "algorithm" header (i
none other). The dialog between the user and the program should look like this:
Enter the elements ( for the end of the line, * at the beginning of the line for the end of the entry):
2 5 1 6 7 *
9 8 9 *
3 3 2 3 *
4 5 1 1 7 3 2 *
*

Matrix after sorting:
9 8 9
4 5 1 1 7 3 2
2 5 1 6 7
3 3 2 3

Enter the elements of the required sequence (* for the end of the line):
2 5 1 6 7 *

The requested sequence is in the 3rd row (after sorting)
Here is my code:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Criterion function
bool Criterion(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b) {
    int max_a = *std::max_element(a.begin(), a.end());
    int max_b = *std::max_element(b.begin(), b.end());

    if (max_a != max_b)
        return max_a > max_b;
    else
        return a > b;
}

// SortByOrderGoodness function
void SortByOrderGoodness(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix) {
    std::sort(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), Criterion);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
    std::string line;
    char ch;

    // Input matrix
    std::cout << "Enter the elements (* for the end of the line, * at the beginning of the line for the end of the entry):\n";
    while (true) {
        std::vector<int> row;
        int num;
        while (std::cin >> num) {
            row.push_back(num);
        }
        if (row.empty()) break;
        matrix.push_back(row);
        std::cin.clear(); // clear the error state
        std::cin >> ch; // read the '*'
    }

    // Sort matrix
    SortByOrderGoodness(matrix);

    // Print sorted matrix
    std::cout << "Matrix after sorting:\n";
    for (const auto& r : matrix) {
        for (const auto& n : r) {
            std::cout << n << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    // Search for sequence
    std::cout << "Enter the elements of the required sequence (* for the end of the line): ";
    std::vector<int> sequence;
    int num;
    while (std::cin >> num) {
        sequence.push_back(num);
    }

    auto it = std::lower_bound(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), sequence, Criterion);
    if (it != matrix.end() && *it == sequence) {
        std::cout << "The requested sequence is in the " << std::distance(matrix.begin(), it) + 1 << "th row (after sorting)\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "The requested sequence is not found in the matrix\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

My program just ends when I have to enter the sequence I need to find.
I can not use sstream :( Is there any way to handle this?

273k just proved my initial feeling about this question correct. It's not worth editing because other people will also edit while I'm editing.

Added a few estra compiler options: Does this help you narrow down the cause of the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/x1W7e6M7v

I added to check if vector is empty because std::max_element function and it is not working :(

Kudos! That's exactly what to check for.  But why is the vector empty? Is it allowed to be empty? If not, what earlier bug is producing an empty vector?

Here is that example code again, but this time printing out sequence after reading it in: https://godbolt.org/z/asWvPo1ds .Hmmmm. Empty sequence.

The bug is here
    if (row.empty()) break;
    matrix.push_back(row);
    std::cin.clear();  // clear the error state
    std::cin >> ch;    // read the '*'

You don't clear std::cin state and '*' is kept in std::cin at the loop break. Therefore sequence can't be filled and is empty. Further call to Criterion() from std::lower_bound() with the empty sequence causes the segmentation fault.
You might want clear the std::cin state and its buffer before the break:
    if (!row.empty()) matrix.push_back(row);
    std::cin.clear();  // clear the error state
    std::cin >> ch;    // read the '*'
    if (row.empty()) break;

